# How to support TLS 1.0 with okhttp in android 4.4 to 5.0

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I am using the source code to connect the website with https://

I am using this code:

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

but it will send back this result:

```
W: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb8b214a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x84dcb770:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
```

I am using the Android 4.4 with okhttp 3.10.0

Comment: Which version of okhttp? Because their website says: "OkHttp initiates new connections with modern TLS features (SNI, ALPN), and falls back to TLS 1.0 if the handshake fails." On the opposite it may be the website you connect to that is not recent enough regarding TLS handling. Did you double check that part too? Otherwise see https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: I am using okhttp 3.10.1 which is the last, with ssl labs, I have find that it support tls 1.0, tls 1.1, tls 1.2

Comment: Did you try various options in https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS like COMPATIBLE_TLS instead of the default MODERN_TLS? Did you try another server just to make sure the problem is really not there?

Comment: Looks to like OkHttp forgot to disable the SSLv2Hello and/or SSLv3 which is used by default on those Android versions (OkHttp does AFAIK not contain an own SSL/TLS implementation, therefore it has to use the one provided by the platform).

Comment: @Robert do you have any idea on how can I fix that?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes, still not working

Comment: OkHttp claims that SSLv3 is complety disabled - if it is still active this is a bug. A Wireshark capture of the connection request could prove that. Just try to establish a HTTPS connection to any server (TCP with or without SSL) running on your computer and capture the SSL_HELLO message. Then you will see what is being sent by your device.

Comment: with ssllabs result, it says that SSLV3 in my site is disabled, it it good or bad?

Comment: the problem is that when I use another hosts like google, I will get the same problem.